# Unity macos xcode with app sandbox problem

Tags: firebase, macos, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

- Unity editor version: 2021.3.17f1 and 2021.3.15f1
- Firebase Unity SDK version: 10.4.0
- Source you installed the SDK: .unitypackage
- Problematic Firebase Component: Auth
- Other Firebase Components in use: Firestore
- Additional SDKs you are using: -
- Platform you are using the Unity editor on: Mac (for mac build) and Windows (for win build)
- Platform you are targeting: Macos and Windows (iOS, Android, and/or desktop)
- Scripting Runtime: Mono (Mono, and/or IL2CPP)
- Pre-built SDK from the [website](https://firebase.google.com/download/unity) or open-source from this repo: website

I built my Unity project with Firebase for both MacOS and Windows platforms. Both sides are working without any problems, but I want to sign my project on MacOS, so I need to add an app sandbox. After adding the app sandbox, my project crashes at the following line:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD5D1.png)

source file of this crash is "google-services-desktop.json and google-services.json" if i remove this file by xcode it doesn't crash but firebase is not working.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foVAX.png)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF0Hb.png)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLP5A.png)

- I moved the "google-services.json" and "google-services-desktop.json" files from within xcode to get them out of appsandbox. This saved my game from crashing but I couldn't access firebase.
- i tried with latest xcode version

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question and links are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't intend to upload it to the App Store, which made the app sandbox optional for me. I found that the application can be signed without the app sandbox by using the DeveloperID. I solved the problem by turning off the app sandbox.